# Wikipedia views to the match trading days

Tags: r, wikipedia, trading

I have data for Wikipedia page views like this

```
library(wikipediatrend)

views <-wp_trend(page = "European debt crisis",from = "2010-01-01",to = "2014-12-31",lang = "en",friendly = TRUE,requestFrom = "wp.trend.tester at wptt.wptt",userAgent = TRUE)

date        count
2010-01-01    128
2010-01-02    142
```

and I have data for S&P500

```
library(quantmod)

startDate = as.Date("2010-01-01")

endDate = as.Date("2014-12-31") 

getSymbols("^GSPC", src = "yahoo", from = startDate, to = endDate) 

Date           Open         High     Low          Close      Volume

2010-01-04     1116.56      1133.87  1116.56      1132.99    3991400000 
2010-01-05     1132.66      1136.63  1129.66      1136.52    2491020000
```

Now I want to extract only those days for Wikipedia Page when trading happened, i.e excluding weekends and holidays and days for unnatural shutdown like Hurricane Sandy etc etc. What will be the easiest way to extract those values

Comment: Could you share a little bit more of source code ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a straighforward subsetting (or filtering) problem:

```
# get the wikipedia views data
library(wikipediatrend)
views <-wp_trend(page = "European debt crisis",from = "2010-01-01",to = "2014-12-31",lang = "en",friendly = TRUE,requestFrom = "wp.trend.tester at wptt.wptt",userAgent = TRUE)

# get the stock trading data
library(quantmod)
startDate = as.Date("2010-01-01")
endDate = as.Date("2014-12-31") 
getSymbols("^GSPC", src = "yahoo", from = startDate, to = endDate)
```

Here's how to subset using `[` in base R:

```
# where are the trading dates in the stock data?
index(GSPC)

# where are the dates in the wikipedia data?
views$date
```

So we want to subset the `views` data frame by the `date` column so that it only contains values found in `index(GSPS)`:

```
# subset wikipedia data by stock data
# pattern is:
# table_to_subset[rule_to_subset_rows, rule_to_subset_columns]
# so to subset the wikipedia view data by the dates of the stock trading
# data we can do this:

wiki_data <- views[views$date %in% index(GSPC), ]
```

You could also use the contributed packages `data.table` or `dplyr` to do this, which might be faster if your data are very large.

Answer (score 0):

yes understood it a bit later and solved it

```
gspcdf<-data.frame(date = index(GSPC), GSPC, row.names=NULL)


CombDF<-merge(views,gspcdf, by.x='date', by.y='date')
```

Comment: It's good style to use spaces around `<-` and `=` and after `,` cf. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html